# de-aggregate for table columns in Greenplum

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, greenplum

I am using `Greenplum`, and I have data like:

```
 id | val 
----+-----
 12 |  12 
 12 |  23 
 12 |  34 
 13 |  23 
 13 |  34 
 13 |  45 
(6 rows)
```

somehow I want the result like:

```
 id | step 
----+-----
 12 |  12 
 12 |  11 
 12 |  11 
 13 |  23 
 13 |  11 
 13 |  11 
(6 rows)
```

How it comes:

First there should be a `Window function`, which execute a `de-aggreagte` function based on `partition by id`

the column `val` is cumulative value, and what I want to get is the step values.

Maybe I can do it like:

```
select deagg(val) over (partition by id) from table_name;
```

So I need the `deagg` function.

Thanks for your help!

P.S and Greenplum is based on postgresql v8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `LAG` function:

```
SELECT id,
    val - lag(val, 1, 0) over (partition BY id ORDER BY val) as step
FROM yourTable
```

Note carefully that `lag()` has three parameters.  The first is the column for which to find the lag, the second indicates to look at the previous record, and the third will cause `lag` to return a default value of zero.

Here is a table showing the table this query would generate:

```
 id | val | lag(val, 1, 0) | val - lag(val, 1, 0)
----+-----+----------------+----------------------
 12 | 12  |      0         |        12
 12 | 23  |      12        |        11
 12 | 34  |      23        |        11
 13 | 23  |      0         |        23
 13 | 34  |      23        |        11
 13 | 45  |      34        |        11
```

Second note: This answer assumes that you want to compute your rolling difference in order of `val` ascending.  If you want a different order you can change the `ORDER BY` clause of the partition.

Comment: thanks, this is real helpful. and easier than what I planned to do.

Comment: Yes, believe me I was also relieved that `LAG` could be used out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

`val` seems to be a cumulative sum. You can "unaggregate" it by subtracting the previous `val` from the current `val`, e.g., by using the `lag` function. Just note you'll have to treat the first value in each group specially, as `lag` will return `null`:

```
SELECT id, val - COALESCE(LAG(val) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY val), 0) AS val
FROM   mytable;
```